# NODE JS: How to change include path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd

I have a problem that when i want to compile  a package, that its looking for the wrong version.

Here is a picture where its all explained ->
http://puu.sh/az4Yp/95f544a7fb.png

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\intrin.h(26): fa
tal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht geöffnet werden: "ammintrin.h": No
such file or directory
```

But i need this: Change to folder 11.0!

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio **11.0**\VC\include\intrin.h(26): fa
tal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht geöffnet werden: "ammintrin.h": No
such file or directory
```

Also here is the whole log:
http://pastebin.com/bgQBrWp2

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you try using the "Visual Studio Command Prompt" for your version of VS to install the module? Or the Windows SDK command prompt?

Comment: Yea anyway i just fixed it by installing Service Pack 1 for version 10.